# Running a function that's defined inside JSON

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm utilizing a Carousel component from Vuetify. I can make it work inputting the raw data, like this:

```
<template>
  <v-carousel>
    <v-carousel-item
      v-for="(item,i) in items"
      :key="i"
      :src="item.src"
      reverse-transition="fade-transition"
      transition="fade-transition"
    ></v-carousel-item>
  </v-carousel>
</template>


<script>
    import json from "../../datajson/imgs.json";
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
          items: [
            {src: require('@/assets/photos/Uso de quebra ventos/1.jpg')},
            {src: require('@/assets/photos/Uso de quebra ventos/2.jpg')}
        ]
  }
```

but I need to acess that items attribute from inside a JSON file, which is like this:

```
    {
        "title": "Uso de quebra ventos",
        "items": [
            {"src": "require('@/assets/photos/Uso de quebra ventos/Capa.jpg')"},
            {"src": "require('@/assets/photos/Uso de quebra ventos/1.jpg')"},
            {"src": "require('@/assets/photos/Uso de quebra ventos/2.jpg')"}
        ]
    }
```

The problem is, when I update the data value to that of the JSON, the JSON srcs are strings, and so the function require doesn't work and it gets interpreted as part of the url.
How can I solve this?
If I try to acess it directly as src: "@/assets/photos/Uso de Quebra ventos/1.jpg" for example, I get Vuetify Image load failed.

What can I do?

Comment: You  can't define functions inside JSON. [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) is a textual data exchange format, and including functions to data is specifically not a part of the standard.

Comment: items = JSON.parse(//your JSON).items;

Comment: How can I store those links then? It's because this component will be dynamic, so depending on the id of the page, it will show a different gallery of images.

Comment: I tried JSON.parse, but it turns into this: 
src:"/img/1.4845b3ce.jpg"
src:"/img/2.12f3e6bf.jpg"
and then the carousel doesn't work and the images don't load either

Comment: you *might* be able to eval it, but you shouldn't.